# altervative to navigatetoURL in Flex 4.5 - not working

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, navigatetourl

Maybe you all know about the issue GoogleChrome and Safari has with using navigatetoURL. It works only in IE. Thus I gathered the following code from a forum. The code is a javascript function place in the html file.  Then there is another function in Flex, which is called when a button is clicked. Part of the code is here:

```
variables.pmsg1 = xml_langue.msg1;
variables.pmsg2 = xml_langue.msg2;
variables.pmsg3 = xml_langue.msg3;
variables.pmsg4 = xml_langue.msg4;
variables.ppaytomode = parentApp.PAYTOMODE;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(dir_web);
request.data = variables;
request.method = "GET";
//navigateToURL(request,"_blank");
postXMLPageRequest(variables, request.toString(), '_blank'); // HERE I AM CALLING THE FLEX FUNCTION
```

THE FLEX FUNCTION BELOW:

public function postXMLPageRequest(data:Object, pageURL:String, window:String=null):void
{
    if (ExternalInterface && ExternalInterface.available)
        ExternalInterface.call("postXMLPageRequest", pageURL, data.encode().toString(), window);
}

THE JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION (found in html file) BELOW:

function postXMLPageRequest(url, xmlString, target, method) 
  {
  method   = method || "POST";
  target   = target || "_blank";

<%----------------------------------------------------------%>
  <%-- Create a form element with the specified attributes. --%>
  <%----------------------------------------------------------%>
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("action",  url);
  form.setAttribute("method",  method);
  form.setAttribute("target",  target);
  form.setAttribute("ENCTYPE", "text/plain");
  form.setAttribute("style",   "display: none");

<%--------------------------------------------------------------------%>
  <%-- Add the XML string as the value to a hidden input to the form. --%>
  <%--------------------------------------------------------------------%>
  var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("type",  "hidden");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("name",  "' + xmlString);
  form.appendChild(hiddenField );

<%-----------------------------------------%>
  <%-- Add the form to the body, submit it --%>
  <%-- then remove the form from the body. --%>
  <%-----------------------------------------%>
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
  document.body.removeChild(form);
  }

However nothing is being executed when I click the button which calls the postXMLPageRequest function>
CAn somebody help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues I see right away. First, you are calling your flex function using

> postXMLPageRequest(variables, **request.toString()**, '_blank');

Even though it extends Object, URLRequest doesn't actually have a toString() method. request.url is the correct way to get the url string.

The second is that you have a syntax error in your javascript. You have a double quote and a single quote rather than a pair of quotes in

> hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "' + xmlString);

Third, you indicate in your call to the flex method that you want to do a GET request. You never actually pass a method type string into the javascript though. If you want the do a get you need to pass "GET" as the fourth parameter of the ExternalInterface call. Otherwise it will default to POST.

Hope that helps.